# Expanding pandas index, where new index values are zeroes

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

I have two series, `series1` and `series2`.

```
series1
```

has an index that is a subset of the index of `series2.`

I want to basically add those new index values to the first series (the ones in series2 but not in series1) and have them be 0 values.

Comment: Please provide more info on (1) what `series1` and `series2` look like and (2) the code you've attempted so far.

Comment: It's simple, just like... S1:  1 2 3. S2: 1 2 3 4. With similar indices, so I want s1 to have a 4th row with index 4 and value 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas `Index` objects have some built-in methods for doing things like set operations. Working from the example data mocked up by svenkatesh, we can get the union of the `s1` and `s2` indexes, and provide a fill value:

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series(range(1, 10), index=range(0,9))
s2 = pd.Series(range(1, 4), index=range(0,3))
# `|` represents the union operation
# This is not an inplace operation by default, so
# you need to assign the result back to `s2` if
# you want to keep the changes
s2.reindex(s2.index | s1.index, fill_value=0)
Out[53]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the example you gave in your comment, I construct two sample series, `s1` and `s2` where each has the same values for common indices. For index values NOT in `s1` but PRESENT in `s2`, I assign values in `s1` to 0.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s1 = pd.Series(range(1, 10), index=range(0,9))

In [3]: s1
Out[3]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    8
8    9
dtype: int64

In [4]: s2 = pd.Series(range(1, 4), index=range(0,3))

In [5]: s2
Out[5]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64

In [6]: join = ~((s1.index.isin(s2.index)))

In [7]: join
Out [7]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool) 

In [8]: s1.loc[join] = 0

In [9]: s1
Out [9]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
dtype: int64
```